# Nested "everything except" in regexp

Tags: regex, nested

I'm writing a program which turns pseudo-regexp into real regexp and have ran into an issue. In pseudo-regexp there is a command *!* which means "everything except" and works with only 1 character. So for example *!a* means everything except a. However this is also allowed: *!(a|b|c)* (everything except a, b and c). Transformed into real regexp it would be *[^a]* and *[^(a|b|c)]* respectively. 
Then if I had a pseudo-regexp like this: *!(a|!b|c)* (or just the letter b...I think) then it would be transformed to look like this: *[^(a|[^b]|c)]*. The problem is that this is actually not a valid regexp (at least according to regex101.com) as apparently nested [^] doesn't work. Is there some alternative way to transform it into valid regexp? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `[^...]` simply contains an enumeration of disallowed characters. No normal regex constructs are available in this context. Thus your attempt includes `(` and `|` and `)` among those disallowed characters.

Comment: You'd have to check Java regexes to get a handle on how to incorporate intersections/unions with the negation operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is, that ^ in square brackets really means "not those characters", but anywhere else, ^ means start of the string. If you will have regexp "^abc", it will match only if string starts with "abc", but "dabc" will not match.

What you are looking for is negative look-ahead symbol **?!** like this:

```
(?!a|[^b]|c)
```

You can find more about it here:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

I also recommend use https://www.debuggex.com/ for visual representation of regexps, it really helps to find a bug.

Comment: I only skimmed the article so I may be wrong but it seems that this symbol is "forgotten" after. So regex like: (?!a)bc used on string "gggabcggg" will make bc valid even if a is in front of it.

Comment: Yes, it is not part of the matched string, it is look-ahead condition. It depends on what you exactly need, which is not clear from the question above. You have more that one bug in your regexp, so it's hard to guess what you want to match exactly. You should be aware that square brackets match only one character, and | or & etc can't be used in there. You can use it only for example [a-zA-Z0-9_] which means you accept only underscore and characters in range a-z, A-Z and 0-9. RegExps does not support inverse matching, so you need to solve it differently.

Comment: And it is not true entirely it's forgotten, but what you wrote is wrong, because "(?!a)bc" is same as "bc", because first condition, that string can't have "a" on 1st position is automatically true by forcing "b" on 1st position. If you want to allow bbc cbc, dbc but not abc, you have to use [^a]bc.

Comment: I tested it and [^(a|b|c)] is valid and is working as intended. For example [^(a|b|c)]fg matches mfg but not bfg or cfg. Not sure what makes my question unclear but to clarify: I will be given pseudo regexp for example    !(a|!b|c). ! means everything except this character in pseudo regexp. So this means every character with the exception of b is nonvalid. I want to transform it into real regexp.

Comment: That's exactly my point because I'm looking for "not those characters" and negative lookahead symbol doesn't seem to provide that.

Comment: Yes, [^(a|b|c)] is valid but does not work as you expected. It is same as  [^abc] for you. As I said, square brackets match only one character and cointain set of characters which are allowed (or not allowed, when list starts with ^). With this, you only specified, that you want one character, which is not a, b, c, (, ) or |. Those round brackets and OR symbol is not bracket and symbol, it is only enlisted character.

Comment: What you want is not easily transferable to regexp, since regexps does not support inverted matches and you can't nest those square brackets. Probably easiest way will be loop thru characters of your pseudo regexp and turn every single negative character into [^x] form. But you will need to resolve ! before (), because this is not supported. Only possible way I can think of is to remember actual ! state and consider it when you are approaching thru loop. You should find easiest way how to transform "!(a|!b|c)" into "[^a]|[b]|[^c]".

Comment: Yeah I guess that would be the best solution. Thanks